# php friendy url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following code on my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^course-details/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ course-details.php?id=$1
```

I think this gave me a URL like this: /cp/course-details/5 where 5 is the id of the course.

But when I go to this address I get 404 not found. Also, our current url is

```
/cp/course-details.php?course-details.php?name=bla-bla-bla&category_id=1
```

and we need a friendly url like this

```
cp/category-name/course-name/
```

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: I just change it to the name of the course...forget about the category

Comment: Is CP a real directory? And where is your .htaccess file?

Comment: yes, CP is a real directory, and .htaccess is in the same level of the cp folder

Comment: @anubhava for now I need a frendly url like this: cp/course-datails/course-name

Comment: @anubhava The url was id=id_number, but I don't want a url like /cp/course-details/123  I need a url like /cp/course-details/course-name, this is why I change the url from id=id_number to name=course-name

Comment: Then you'd need `^cp/course-details/...`. `^` means "start of string", and your path string starts with `cp`, yet you're telling the regex to only match strings that start with `course`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in your htaccess file if the php file is in the cp dir. Since it appears your are developing in a `subfolder(peppers)` of your dev box you can try this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /peppers/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^cp/course-details/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

If this is for production then you can use this in the .htaccess file in the root.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^cp/course-details/([^/]+)/?$ /cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I get 404 error, this an example link on develoment http://localhost:8888/peppers/cp/course-details/bla-bla-bla and production
http://www.pepperscope.com/cp/course-details/bla-bla-bla

Comment: I modified the regex in the rule. Try it that way and see how it works. Also clear your cache before trying it again.

Comment: Same error 404, I don't understand what happen here

Comment: This is my php code for the link <a href="course-details/<?php echo preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $course[course_name]); ?>"

Comment: Try putting it in the main .htaccess file in the root and use my update.

Comment: I'm in the root of the proyect

Comment: Dude are you trying this on your dev box or your prod? I think that's messing you up. What is the root of your project peppers? or localhost/? You have all these sudirs

Comment: I'm using mamp and this is the path: mamp/htdocs/peppers/ on my production is web/

Comment: also, the exact error is: The requested URL /peppers/cp/course-details/bla-bla-bla.php was not found on this server. The server is trying to find a php file with the name of the course

Comment: this works, on production and my localhost, but the server show the page of the course, without the css

Comment: Prepend path to your CSS file with the `/`. example. `/path/to/style.css` or add the base tag to the head section example `<base href="http://pepperscope.com/css/">`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^course-details/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/.*$ course-details.php?id=$1&category_id=$2
```

With that, you can use URL like `course-details/1/5/category-name/course-name`

Because URL allow: `course-details/category_id/id/what-ever-you-want`